# Как научиться работать с api ? ( основы )

Tags: delphi, rest

Я написал небольшую программу для торговли ( не 1С ) и она работает у меня примерно на 20 точках. Но сейчас из-за изменений в законах мне надо научиться сканировать молоко и отправлять через `api` информацию о продажах в честный знак

Я не умею работать с `api` и поэтому все мои точки надо будет закрыть или перевести на другое ПО до `20.01.2022`

Пожалуйста, посоветуйте книгу или ресурс для изучения, времени мало, но есть желание

Comment: Вы хотя бы показали как это апи выглядит. Не все в курсе, что такое "честный знак" и зачем оно вообще нужно. Но с большой вероятностью Вам нужен просто какой-нибудь http клиент (TIdHttp еще живо? synapse) и просто аккуратно заполнить все поля

Comment: Ну видимо нужно читать документацию у этого самого честного знака, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal да, но мне сказали, что она полна неточностей, а мне нужен уровень ноль для обучения

Comment: Ну так документация и попробовать тестовые запросы поделать: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/REST_Client_Library#Accessing_a_Simple_API Можно еще в дополнение взять готовый клиент postman или insomnia, и какой-нибудь rest сервер вроде https://pokeapi.co/, чтобы пощупать технологию перед написанием кода. Вроде у честного знака есть тестовый сервер по документации и примеры из postman, можно будет с ним так же поработать потом.

Comment: Открыть и прочесть документацию

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer если вы про документацию Честного знака, то она очень кривая, если вы про другую документацию, то пожалуйста напишите мне, какую именно документацию вы имеете в виду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Delphi есть отличный инструмент для работы с REST из коробки.
Позволяет во время дизайна настроить и посмотреть на работу API. Очень прост в использовании и стабильно работает.

Вкладка REST Client, компоненты TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, TRESTResponse

Вдобавок, есть инструмент для тестирования и генерации компонентов REST Debugger, который поможет разобраться с API.

Конкретно по вопросу: вот [тут](https://webdelphi.ru/2013/09/delphi-xe5-rest-client-library/) есть подробный разбор с примерами.